# Make a class method callable from anywhere in your program but not outside programs

Tags: java, access-modifiers

I created a class MyLogger that extends java.util.Logger in my project and I want each class to use the same logger therefore there is a static `getLogger()` method which returns a `Logger` object.

The plan is for this to be a jar file that can be included in other people's programs, but I don't want them to be able to use this custom logger (ie. if they want logging they need to set it up themselves with their own logger).

Is there any way to allow the `MyLogger` class be in its own package while allowing the rest of the classes in my project/jar be able to access the `getLogger()` method, but not allow classes outside my project to call it (kinda like package private, but for the whole project) or is the only way to put it in my "parent" package?

Comment: *kinda like package private, but for the whole project* No. There is no such access modifier.

Comment: As an aside, have you evaluated [SLF4J](http://www.slf4j.org)?

Comment: You will be able to do this in Java 9 using modules. See [this table](http://stackoverflow.com/a/33627846/276052) for reference.

Answer (score 2):

Yes, you may noticed you can not put a class into package `java.util`, the technology is the JSA. You could use the SecurityManager (who uses the accesscontroller). If the library who is calling the logger-event is not certified by your private certificate, it throws the unchecked `AccessControlException`.

You will find a good example in the FileOutputStream like this:

```
SecurityManager security = System.getSecurityManager();
if (security != null) {
    security.checkWrite(name); // throws ACE
}
```

To authenticate a complete JVM and disable the checks you could add the private key to jdk-xxx/jre/lib/security/cacerts (keystore).